# Pass variable Layer in function parameters in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I want to pass this `layer = self.iface.activeLayer()` into a function `import_meta(self, layer)` to be used like a layer object  `dpr = layer.dataProvider()`

But when I run the script I get error  `AttributeError: 'xdr_ImportMeta' object has no attribute 'dataProvider'  dpr = layer.dataProvider()`

I guess the variable's type `layer` doesn't pass as I want.
This is the code:

```
def import_meta(self, layer):
    dpr = layer.dataProvider()

def run(self):
    layer = self.iface.activeLayer()
    self.import_meta(self, layer)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, when you call a function (defined in a class) in own class, you don't need to use `self` argument. Python implicitly passes `self` as first argument to the function.

So, try to change `self.import_meta(self, layer)` into `self.import_meta(layer)`.